# How can I execute ArmorStands around me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to execute from the *red* ArmorStand to the *blue* ArmorStands. And the *blue* ArmorStands should say "hi".

[image]

My problem is, that I can't use tags. So if I use "r=2" only the ArmorStands next to the red one will say "hi".

How can I select all eight blue ArmorStands without tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to fiddle with `execute`'s vertical offset until `r=2` only selects the 8 you want:

```
/execute @e[name=Red] ~ ~1 ~ /execute @e[r=2,name=!Red] ~ ~ ~ /say hi
```

By placing the start of the spherical selection further up, you can avoid selecting the further away ones that you don't want to select.

A side view of this will look something like:

[image: Spherical offset]

---

Alternatively, you can use the `dy, dx, dz` cuboid volume selectors, again with an initial offset:

```
/execute @e[name=Red] ~-1 ~ ~-1 /execute @e[dx=2,dy=1,dz=2,name=!Red] ~ ~ ~ /say hi
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Cuboid offset]